# Displaying a selected object as string in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios, jquery-select2

Below is my html code that am using to implement select2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>department</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ProgramForm">

          <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="department">Department<span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                        <select v-model="department"   class="form-control select2" >
                            <option> </option>
                            <option  v-for="department in departmentData" v-bind:value="department">{{department.departmentName}}</option>
                        </select>
                  </div>
            </div>                        

               <p>Selected{{department}}</p>
</div>
```

My script section is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function () {
    var programFormVM=new Vue({
        el:"#ProgramForm",
        data:function(){    
            return {
                department:{},
                departmentData:[
                                { "id": 1, "departmentCode": "HR", "departmentName": "Human Resource" },
                                { "id": 2, "departmentCode": "ENG", "departmentName": "Engineering" }, 
                                { "id": 3, "departmentCode": "AE", "departmentName": "Agricultural Economics" },
                                { "id": 4, "departmentCode": "FS", "departmentName": "Field Station" }, 
                                { "id": 5, "departmentCode": "ARC", "departmentName": "Architecture" }
                               ]        

            }

        },
        created:function (){
        },
        methods:{

        },
    }); 
  $('.select2').select2({
    placeholder: "Select a department"
   }).on('change', function(e) {
      //  var data = $(".select2 option:selected").val();
        programFormVM.department=$(".select2 option:selected").val();
      });   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to display the object as a string. As it is, an getting [object Object].I Have tried .text() but its giving the name of the department only. I my case i need the whole object but as a string like { "id": 5, "departmentCode": "ARC", "departmentName": "Architecture" }. Please help out. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v-bind:value="department.id"
```

```
const selectedValue = <value from select>
const selectedDepartment = this.departmentData.find(x => x.id === selectedVal)
```

Comment: Hi Anatoly. How should i apply it in  ES5.  Thanks for response

Comment: You can use babel to polyfill the find method or just use the for loop statement.

Comment: Am grateful for that!